# How to set Keycloak as Identity provider to access underlying third party applications data

Tags: next.js, keycloak, next-auth

I am been lurking around keycloak for some time but couldn't find a solution for my scenario mentioned below.

End Goal: User logs into Next App. clicks on the login button and logs into keycloak (with keycloak credentials). In the background, the user is also logged into a third-party application (OpenID available). (User will have 0 direct interaction with third-party application)
End result of the process should be an access token which can later be used to make authorized API calls to third-party applications.

*in the future there can be multiple underlying third-party applications that my main app needs access to but I want the user to only enter keycloak credentials and nothing else.
and of course, have access token or tokens idk which one would work in this case to access APIs of these third-party applications (service provider).

I want to know what steps I have to follow if there is any documentation for the type of case I have. It should be simple SSO I guess but I couldn't find much

My main app is in Next.js where I have already set up the environment to get access tokens from keycloak via next-auth.